# Configure OpenVPN client to have public IP

Tags: openvpn, route

Good morning,

I'm currently trying to bring a public IP address directly to a VPN client. I'm using OpenVPN.

Firstly, I've made bridge br0 on the server's side and I've adjusted OpenVPN configuration to use tap0 which is already included in the bridge.

Now, I'm in client side and I'm connecting to the VPN. The server pushed successfully the public IP address, but my default gateway stay the same as without VPN.

I've tried to adjust it with some route add & route del but I can't connect to Internet. Here is my current route -n result:

```
0.0.0.0         54.x.x.254      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
51.x.x.194      54.x.x.254      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tap0
54.x.x.254      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap0
147.x.x.x       192.168.137.129 255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

I think that there is something wrong on this route table.

Note: to use the IP address directly on my OpenVPN server, here is my configuration:

```
IP Address  51.x.x.194
Gateway     54.x.x.254
Netmask     255.255.255.255
```

147.x.x.x is my OpenVPN server's IP address, 51.x.x.194 is the IP allocated for the VPN client, and 54.x.x.254 is the gateway (both for 147.x.x.x and 51.x.x.194).

So, anyone have idea where I was wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a strange that the default gateway IP address `54.x.x.254` is looked via `eth0`.  It should be `tap0`.

Comment: Server or client side?

Comment: I think this is client side. It is from: `Here is my current route -n result:`